# Best method for making segmented rings for wood turning?

Tags: wood, turning

I am a wood turner, and like to do larger bowls.  For segmented bowls, where you glue of rings of say 10 or 12 segments, then stack and glue segments to make the rough bowl blank, what is the best method for cutting accurate segments?

- Table saw & saw sled;
- Chop or miter saw; or
- Other?

Comment: Regardless of what you use to cut the segments, glue up half-rings, and true the half-rings (usually by sanding) before gluing them to make a full ring. Takes away any minor errors in a manner that is not generally noticeable.

Comment: If you are looking to make the rings you may want to look into a ringmaster.
It allows you to make a bowl out of a flat board, but I really hesitate to call it "turning" ...